# How to solve npm error "Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to learn react.
So I have this sample code for the full-stack react voting app.
And I am trying to get it to work but after running `npm install` followed by `npm run start`.
I receive the following error.
When I run `npm run start` can anyone help me with this issue:

```
ERROR in ./assets/styles/main.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.relative (path.js:1162:5)
    at Object.loader (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:78:72)
    at runLoaders (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at /home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at /home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:70:14
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./assets/styles/main.scss
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index.tsx ./assets/styles/main.scss

ERROR in ./assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf?8gpjd2
Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.relative (path.js:1162:5)
    at Object.loader (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:78:72)
 @ ./assets/styles/main.scss 17:36-74
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index.tsx ./assets/styles/main.scss
    ERROR in ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.eot
    Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
        at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
        at Object.relative (path.js:1162:5)
        at Object.loader (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:78:72)
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css 5:36-64
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--3-3!./assets/styles/main.scss
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.ttf
    Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
        at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
        at Object.relative (path.js:1162:5)
        at Object.loader (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:78:72)
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css 7:36-64
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--3-3!./assets/styles/main.scss
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.svg
    Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
        at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
        at Object.relative (path.js:1162:5)
        at Object.loader (/home/topdev/work/hubbers-front/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:78:72)
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css 8:36-64
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--3-3!./assets/styles/main.scss
webpack: Failed to compile.
```